# Running RSpec on Google App Engine via JRuby

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, rspec, jruby

I'm trying to write some tests (RSpec) against the AppEngine and its datastore. I've tried to load the environment and tests via:

```
appcfg.rb run -S spec app/tests/
```

And I end up with the following error:

> spec:19: undefined method `bin_path'
>   for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

I can run non-appengine specs just fine by running:

```
spec app/tests/
```

Any suggestions on how to get RSpec up and running with JRuby and Google App Engine would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Some versions numbers for your face:

jruby 1.4.0 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 174) (2009-11-02 6586) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_17) [x86_64-java]

rspec (1.3.0)
appengine-apis (0.0.12)
appengine-jruby-jars (0.0.6)
appengine-rack (0.0.6)
appengine-sdk (1.3.1)
appengine-tools (0.0.10.1)
dm-appengine (0.0.7)
dm-core (0.10.2)

Answer (score 0):

spec:19: undefined method `bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

looks like

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/205780